# Error : 'oItem' is a 'variable' but used like a 'method'

Tags: c#

I'm relatively new to C# coding in the .NET framework. I'm using Visual studios 2010. I feel like this is a simple problem but whatever I seem to try with the visibility, it doesn't work. 
I want to just convert the code from VB.Net to C# . It works fine on Vb but when I write it into C# it gives an error.

Here is the Error:  'oItem' is a 'variable'  but is used like a 'method'

Please take a look at the code and tell me what I'm overlooking. I have searched the questions of course as well as googling, but the problem is that mostly this error has to do with arrays. For me it does NOT.

## In  c#

```
foreach ( object oItem in modWeldedCylinder.ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.FormNavigationOrder)
{
 if (oItem(clsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.EOrderOfFormNavigationArraylist.CurrentFormName).ToString().Equals(modWeldedCylinder.ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.ObjCurrentForm.Name))
                {
                    Form oForm = null;
                    Form oCurrentForm = null;

        }
}
```

In VB.Net

```
For Each oItem As Object In ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.FormNavigationOrder

   If oItem(clsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.EOrderOfFormNavigationArraylist.CurrentFormName).ToString.Equals(ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.ObjCurrentForm.name) Then
            Dim oForm As Form = Nothing
            Dim oCurrentForm As Form = Nothing
```

Comment: what type/class is oItem? Post its definition here. for `object o;`  there exists no `o()` in C#.

Comment: oItem  is  Object type

Comment: wrong. Its true type must be something different. Use debugger, Quick watch, third column.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [] instead of () after oItem:

```
foreach ( object oItem in modWeldedCylinder.ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.FormNavigationOrder)
{
 if (oItem[clsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.EOrderOfFormNavigationArraylist.CurrentFormName].ToString().Equals(modWeldedCylinder.ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.ObjCurrentForm.Name))
                {
                    Form oForm = null;
                    Form oCurrentForm = null;

        }
}
```

Comment: If i Use [ ] insted of () then there  is again   Error .                                            Error :  Cann't apply Indexing with [ ] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Ok, then you are using a default method on the object when your using (). C# doesn't have default methods so you'll have to find out what method/function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are place-holders for data / classes. They look like this:

```
int j = 6;
```

Methods are functions and are defined like this:

```
public int GetAValue()
{
   return 6;
}
```

And used like this:

```
int x = GetAValue();
```

Your `foreach` loop defines a variable `oItem`:

```
foreach ( object oItem in ...
```

The variable `oItem` can only be used to set its value or use its value or sub-values, it cannot be used like a method. Currently you are using `oItem` like a method, `oItem(...)`. Notice the `()` to the right of the variable name.

I personally don't know VB, so I cannot translate your code for you. Though if I were to take a crack at it, I'd do this:

```
var formname = (clsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.EOrderOfFormNavigationArraylist.CurrentFormName)oItem;

if (formname.ToString().Equals(ObjClsWeldedCylinderFunctionalClass.ObjCurrentForm.name)) 
{
   // do something if true
}
```

As it looks like you are trying to cast the object to the class inside the `()` and then use that to do a string comparison. By placing the `()` to the left of the variable name, we cast the object to the class on the left side, and use it.

You may be able to short-cut the whole procedure in the `foreach`, like so:

```
foreach (var formname in ...
```

If the object returned by the container is already the object you are casting too, you save a step.